# RaisePropertyChanged in a nested ObservableCollection not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am right now using a nested ObservableCollection to fill in the rows of a DataGrid with the inner ObservableCollection holding information regarding each cell as follows:

```
    public class MemoryTable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _Address;
        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return _Address;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Address != value)
                {
                    _Address = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
        }

        bool _NextRowOverflow;
        public bool NextRowOverflow
        {
            get
            {
                return _NextRowOverflow;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_NextRowOverflow != value)
                {
                    _NextRowOverflow = value;
                }
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<DataAssets> _DataSpace;
        public ObservableCollection<DataAssets> DataSpace
        {
            get
            {
                return _DataSpace;
            }
            set
            {
                _DataSpace = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DataSpace");
            }
        }

        public MemoryTable()
        {
            DataSpace = new ObservableCollection<DataAssets>();
        }

        public class DataAssets : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            string _Addresses;
            public string Addresses
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Addresses;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_Addresses != value)
                    {
                        _Addresses = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("Addresses");
                    }
                }
            }

            string _Values;
            public string Values
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Values;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_Values != value)
                    {
                        _Values = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("Values");
                    }
                }
            }

            string _ToolTip;
            public string ToolTip
            {
                get
                {
                    return _ToolTip;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_ToolTip != value)
                    {
                        _ToolTip = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("ToolTip");
                    }
                }
            }

            Brush _Color;
            public Brush Color
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Color;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_Color != value)
                    {
                        _Color = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
                    }
                }
            }

            string _ConvertedValue;
            public string ConvertedValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return _ConvertedValue;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_ConvertedValue != value)
                    {
                        _ConvertedValue = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("ConvertedValue");
                    }
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And want it to update whenever I change one of the values in the DataAsset class, however whenever I change a value by such a means:

```
NextRow.DataSpace[i].Color = Brushes.Yellow;
```

None of the cells update, the workaround i made for doing this is to clear and rewrite the entire ObservableCollection like this:

```
            ObservableCollection<MemoryTable> Temp = new ObservableCollection<MemoryTable>();
        foreach (var item in MemoryTable)
        {
            if (Temp.IndexOf(item) < 0)
            {
                Temp.Add(item);
            }
        }

        MemoryTableDisplay.Clear();
        foreach (var item in Temp)
        {
            if (MemoryTableDisplay.IndexOf(item) < 0)
            {
                MemoryTableDisplay.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

By this method I am able to force the UI to display the changes, however when moving further to working on a larger set of data, this method takes too long to accomplish, is it possible to have the inner properties to cause an update for the entire ObservableCollection?

Thank you!

Comment: `foreach (var item in MemoryTable)` is `MemoryTable` supposed to be `MemoryTableDisplay`

Comment: >>takes too long to accomplish, ` MemoryTableDisplay.Clear();` why are u cleaning and adding it again and u r using `Temp` list to check already exist value its best u check about Distinct  in linq

Comment: and ObservableCollection will update the ui need to check the binding wt happend why its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
NextRow.DataSpace[i].Color = Brushes.Yellow;
```

After writing down one more statement like this.

```
NextRow.DataSpace= NextRow.DataSpace;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, but could I know the reason why it does and does it have anything to do with the raisepropertychange?